# Can i parse JSON remotely from another server dynamically generated php page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, dynamic

I've been attempting to make this work reading everything, but no luck so far. I generate JSON with php for some records using json_encode and I have it output to a .php page on the server - and example is below:

```
 [{"number":1,"name":"Lizzie","image":"http://scienceblogs.com/scientificactivist/wp-content/blogs.dir/392/files/2012/04/i-dcb85296b3695e8ce6d1ae4d660cea30-Smiley-face.gif"}]
```

On another server, i'd like to ideally read this JSON output and echo it to the page, but I can seem to read it locally but not remotely. Here is an example how far I got with the code:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.server.com/json.php",function(ajaxresult){
$("#number").append(ajaxresult.Number);
$("#name").append(ajaxresult.Name);
$("#image").append(ajaxresult.Image);
});
```

How ever this code will read a local .json file and write the elements out - but not a remote one and consequently not the dynamicly generated remote one.

Any hints to what I've done wrong?

Comment: Check about [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: You can't perform cross-domain requests through javascript without either A) using JSONP ( as mentioned above ), or B) having cross-origin-resource-sharing enabled.

Comment: It is because of [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) restrictions of the browser

Comment: try adding "?callback=?" at the end of the url (oops I may be late)

Answer (score 0):

Save the dynamically generated JSON as a temporary local file and read it from there.